# Which audio codecs are supported for HLS?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, http-live-streaming, fairplay

Does HLS protocol specify audio codec? If it does, which are supported?

I've tried to search, but found different lists:

> MP3, HE-AAC or AC-3

according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming#Architecture)

> AAC, AAC-LC, HE-AAC (accPlus) v1 & v2, MP3

according to [this](https://wmspanel.com/nimble/features)

> AAC-LC, HE-AACV1-2, AC-3, and EC-3

according to [FairPlay overview](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/FairPlay_Streaming_Server_SDK_v3.0/FairPlayStreamingOverview.pdf) (which is subset of HLS)

Comment: Note that AAC-LC, HE-AAC v1, HE-AAC v2 all fit within ADTS, and can be decoded by almost all players.  It's all AAC, and can be used with HLS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would refer to the HLS specification. From [section 3.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-20#section-3.4):

> Supported Packed Audio formats are AAC with ADTS
> framing [ISO_13818_7]; MP3 [ISO_13818_3]; AC-3 [AC_3]; and Enhanced
> AC-3 [AC_3].

Comment: Oddly https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http-live-streaming/hls-authoring-specification-for-apple-devices lists Apple Lossless and FLAC, too and links a newer draft even if that does not mention those.